Is it feasible to run part of test cases parallelly and part of test cases sequentially at the same time in Playwright
I need to run my automation test suite on multiple workers to reduce execution time.  There are a few test cases that use the same endpoint with different configurations. please refer the bellow scenarios

validate ordering flow by disabling the delivery feature.
validate ordering flow by enabling the delivery feature.

when the web automation suite runs on multiple workers these test cases run parallel at the same time. 1st test cases start test execution by disabling the delivery feature. but when 2nd test cases start, it enables the delivery feature.  so what I need is, for this kind of test case should run sequentially to avoid this kind of conflict.
but I have test cases that don't change any backend configurations. those test scenarios use the default configuration. so those test cases can be executed parallelly. it will reduce the execution time too.
To address 1st issue, I need to run some of the test cases sequentially( doesn't matter if those run on multiple workers. The only thing I need to validate is those should execute sequentially ) . to reduce execution time I need to run some of the test cases parallelly using multiple workers.
is this possible with Playwright ?  is there any way to configure this kind of setup?

A concrete example of your tests and what you tried would make it easier to understand your use case and come up with a solution proposal.

I have updated the description please check now

Thanks, but I don't see any code here or a page under test so it's still pretty vague. Generally, you shouldn't need to do what you're trying to do, so there may be a better way if you don't mind providing full context and concrete code. If you need to test some sort of parallel behavior, you'd normally do it in a single test case, not running multiple at once. Tests should be idempotent.
